# How to account for blank cell when when pairing values from two columns

Tags: google-apps-script

I am grabbing the values(email and formLink) from two columns of a google sheet, building an email, then using the email value as the recipient and linking a prefilled google form in the email body. But when the email cell is blank, its essentially skipping that cell and bumping up the position of the next email address, so when the script gets the form link, now they are mismatched and sending the wrong prefilled form link to the wrong recipient. How do resolve this issue?

```
function sendRSVP() {
 var notificationListSpreadsheetId = 'Link_to_sheet'; 
spreadsheet ID var notificationListSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(notificationListSpreadsheetId).getSheetByName('Sheet1');

 var emailAddresses = notificationListSheet.getRange('D2:D').getValues().flat().filter(String);

 var subject = 'RSVP';
 var body = 'BODY<br><br>'
   + `EMAIL<br><br>`
   + `MESSAGE<br><br>`
   + `BODY`;

 var imageUrl = 'imageUrl';
 var buttonText = 'RSVP';

 for (var i = 0; i < emailAddresses.length; i++) {
   var emailAddress = emailAddresses[i];
   var emailBody = createEmailBody(body, imageUrl, buttonText, notificationListSheet, i + 2); // Assuming data starts from row 2
   sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, emailBody);
 }
}

function createEmailBody(body, imageUrl, buttonText, sheet, row) {
 var formLink = sheet.getRange('G' + row).getValue(); // Assuming the link is in column G
 var headerImage = `<img src link">`;
 var rsvpButton = `<a href="${formLink}" style="display: inline-block; margin-top: 15px; padding: 10px 20px; background-color: #4CAF50; color: white; text-decoration: none; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; border-radius: 5px;">${buttonText}</a>`;
 return `${headerImage}<p>${body}</p>${rsvpButton}`;
}

function sendEmail(recipient, subject, body) {
 MailApp.sendEmail({
   to: recipient,
   subject: subject,
   body: 'You need an HTML-enabled email client to view this message.',
   htmlBody: body,
   //replyTo: 'XXX',
   name: "XXX"
 });
}
```

Comment: Can you share a dummy sheet file with sample data for replication purposes?

Comment: You have a typo of some  error in the second line of your example something to do with spreadhsheet id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `emailAddresses` is retrieved with `notificationListSheet.getRange('D2:D').getValues().flat().filter(String);`, in this case, when the cell value is empty, the cell is skipped. But, in the function `createEmailBody`, you are using `i + 2` with `var emailBody = createEmailBody(body, imageUrl, buttonText, notificationListSheet, i + 2);`. In this case, when the cell value of column "D" is empty, the row number of column "G" is not correct. I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue.

And, from your showing script, I guessed that your emails and formLinks are put into columns "D" and "G", respectively. If my understanding is correct, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function sendRSVP() {
  var notificationListSpreadsheetId = 'Link_to_sheet';
  var notificationListSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(notificationListSpreadsheetId).getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var values = notificationListSheet.getRange('D2:G' + notificationListSheet.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues().filter(([d]) => d);
  var subject = 'RSVP';
  var body = 'BODY<br><br>' + `EMAIL<br><br>` + `MESSAGE<br><br>` + `BODY`;
  var imageUrl = 'imageUrl';
  var buttonText = 'RSVP';
  values.forEach(([emailAddress, , , formLink]) => {
    var emailBody = createEmailBody(body, imageUrl, buttonText, notificationListSheet, formLink);
    sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, emailBody);
  });
}

function createEmailBody(body, imageUrl, buttonText, sheet, formLink) {
  var headerImage = `<img src link">`;
  var rsvpButton = `<a href="${formLink}" style="display: inline-block; margin-top: 15px; padding: 10px 20px; background-color: #4CAF50; color: white; text-decoration: none; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; border-radius: 5px;">${buttonText}</a>`;
  return `${headerImage}<p>${body}</p>${rsvpButton}`;
}

function sendEmail(recipient, subject, body) {
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: recipient,
    subject: subject,
    body: 'You need an HTML-enabled email client to view this message.',
    htmlBody: body,
    //replyTo: 'XXX',
    name: "XXX"
  });
}
```

- When this script is run, first, the values are retrieved from columns "D" to "G". And, the retrieved values are filtered by column "D". By this, the value of column "G" corresponding to column "D" is used.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: @dboyd08 Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

May be you won't have the problem if you try this:

```
var emailAddresses = notificationListSheet.getRange('D2:D' + notificationListSheet.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
```